using pandas to number and coerce to force values to ints and still not working
Confused when I am trying to coerce dataframe to numeric. It appears to work when I look at structure but then I still get errors:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Code:
df = df_leads.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') code here

df.info()

Returns: Columns: 133 entries, org_size_1_99 to engagement_Type_webpage visits dtypes: float64(107), int64(26) memory usage: 3.1 MB
next line of code:
sum(df['target']).astype(int)

returns: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Please provide a [mre] of df_leads

There are values in your data that cannot be treated as numeric, because they aren't numbers. You can see in the error itself that there are still strings present. That means you cannot blanket a statement like that without excluding, or ignoring them.
This is a more stable approach:
df = df_leads.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df.info()

nan_count = df['target'].isnull().sum()
print(f"Number of NaN values in 'target': {nan_count}")

df['target'] = df['target'].fillna(0)

sum_result = df['target'].sum().astype(int)
print(f"Sum of 'target': {sum_result}")


"there are still strings present", the purpose of errors='coerce' is to convert all non-numeric values to NaN, thus there cannot be strings after converting.

Yea, and there are often times where it does not work correctly. Especially when assumptions are made about how clean the data might be and when there are mixed typings. You're correct in your explanation, but there are many little edge cases that will prevent coerce from doing what it's intended, and leave strings present within the data. I see it all the time.

Can you provide one reproducible example of that?

This answer makes no sense. If there was a string in df['target'], fillna(0) would not fill it and sum would fail the same way. My guess, OP did something wrong with their code and the error was not reproducible.
